# How long do questions live in the "Reopen votes" review queue?

Tags: discussion, reopen-review

My [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70002488/what-can-standalone-express-do) "*What can standalone Express do?*" was "automatically deleted 6 months ago by CommunityBot". This happened after it was downvoted and closed. Since I do not understand or see any reasons for the removal, I've voted the undelete it, as well as somebody else (thank you!) but it still needs another vote.

I am still interested in an answer, and perhaps I would be able to provide one myself someday, so I'm curious if this question would ever get in a review queue, given how old it is now and that review queues seem quite busy already from new questions? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: That's not a good question, though

Comment: To rephrase the above: that question is not a good question *for this site*.  It is off-topic for this site and might be best asked on other (non-stack exchange) sites that invite broad questions that invite discussion.

Comment: Fair enough, I respect your opinion. I still do not understand why, and I'm not exactly new here. But to be clear, this post is more about how the review queue handles old questions.

Comment: One other related issue is how the community bot targets questions for deletion, and when it performs this task.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what that means. My understanding is that the bot deleted the question due to it being closed and/or the downvotes.

Comment: What has the Reopen Review queue to do with undeleting a question?

Comment: Isn't that what happens when someone votes to undelete a question? How else do questions end up in the "Reopen votes" queue?

Comment: @Nagev: They are in the reopen queue when someone votes to **reopen** a question, not when voting to **undelete**. There is no queue that reviews undelete votes.

Comment: there is no undelete queue

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. So, if I understand correctly, the only chance of a question being undeleted is if someone with enough reputation to see the hidden question (not sure how) happens to vote to undelete it...

Comment: Yes, there are 10K-tools that have a limited list of posts that recently got an undelete vote. But that is not a queue and on SO due to its sheer size your post would be quickly pushed of that list due to newer undelete votes coming in.

Comment: I mean... no 3rd party middleware is doing anything that you couldn't in theory do on your own. An example of such code would in fact be the 3rd party middleware's source.

Comment: I get that. Being able to use the vast amount of middleware available for Express certainly seems like a good reason to me. What I want to know, is what *other* reasons there may be for using Express, especially since I tend to favor writing my own code for many things. And knowing those extra reasons may only come from experience with Express, which I don't have, and might not have unless I have the motivation! Hence the question...

Comment: it's just a... weird question. The only valid answer is "Yes." and I'm pretty sure you already knew that.

Comment: So the answer to "what can standalone express do?" is "yes"? Sorry, don't get it... I don't know what you mean also by what I already knew, but one thing I learned many times from experience, is to not make assumptions.

Comment: "Everything that not standalone express could do. You could even do everything express does without express." It's just neatly packaged code. you could always recreate it yourself, every bit of it.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question in a useful way without making assumptions. If you mean what can you do with express without creating your own middleware, that's an entirely different question, but what can you do with express without 3rd party packages? that's just a misunderstanding of what packages are.

Comment: Well, if I could not make it clear enough for others to understand and it's not useful to anyone else, than perhaps it is best for it to stay deleted. But I will give it one final shot. If you look at the list under "Express has the following built-in  middleware functions" in my question, you can see that Express does bring some functionality of its own. That's the sort of thing I am looking for. Whether its built-in, perhaps undocumented middleware, or something that someone might say, I haven't used any middleware, but Express itself saved me a lot of time with such and such...

Comment: By the way, with my earlier comment regarding assumptions, I simply meant that I didn’t want to make assumptions about what standalone Express can do, that’s why I posted  the question. Sorry if that came across differently.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let me summarize what has been exchanged in the comments.

There is no review queue for undelete votes. The reopen review queue only holds questions that got closed and then got a re-open vote or got edited into shape. So voting to undelete your question doesn't put it in the re-open queue.

If your post was deleted by either the roomba or community votes, your only option is to cast an undelete vote and then wait for users with undelete privileges to follow suit.

There is a very small chance your undelete vote will get noticed by a 10k-er in the so called [10K-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days). Instead you might try to attract the attention of 10k-ers. Well known places are Meta and Chat. Make sure you have a strong argument why undeletion is warranted.

A post that isn't deemed a good fit for the topicality of Stack Overflow is unlikely to get undeleted. Sometimes it is better to ask along the lines of *What improvements does this post needs so it would survive undeletion?*. That is important because if a post is undeleted and then left in the state which caused it to be deleted in the first place and it is bound to be deleted again, even by the roomba. The latter can be brutal if you finally managed to get your post undeleted late on Saturday, as the Roomba runs weekly on Sunday 00:00 UTC-ish.

Just to be transparent: [there are over 50 thousand posts with pending undelete votes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1594010)

Comment: Perhaps reinterate the rules for automatic deletion (and/or link to such information)? MSE FAQ: *[How can a post be deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222)*

Comment: From your link, I can see why the question was deleted. My comment is that it all happened too quickly: the downvotes, the closing, and the automatic deletion. I still do not understand what caused such reaction to my question, and can only guess that a few people misundestood my question or mistakenly thought that there was some hidden intention behind it. Anyway, my question aside, I personally think Roomba should give more time for questions to be exposed to a wider audience, perhaps with exceptions. But that's up to Stackoverflow to decide if they want to review the process.